# How can i save data without database?

Tags: django, templates, view

How can i save data from django form template without database and javascript? just use views and template?
I have a problem with inserting data on django templates. I just can insert 1x if i insert again the data is renew, cannot adding the data

Comment: you can't do that without storing data or using javascript. you have to store data in a place ( file , database, ... ) to reuse it again

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing your code. Please add a [mcve]